# $\sup_{k\geq0}|x_{n+k}-x_n|\leq\sup_{k,l\geq0}|x_{n+k}-x_{n+l}|\leq2\sup_{k\geq0}|x_{n+k}-x_n|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

How to prove that $$\sup_{k\geq0}|x_{n+k}-x_n|\leq\sup_{k,l\geq0}|x_{n+k}-x_{n+l}|\leq2\sup_{k\geq0}|x_{n+k}-x_n|$$ for every real sequence $\{x_n\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n\in \Bbb N$. Since $\{|x_{n+k} - x_n| : k \geq 0\} \subset \{|x_{n+k} - x_{n+l}| : k,l \geq 0\}$ we have
$$\sup_{k\geq0}|x_{n+k}-x_n|= \sup \{|x_{n+k} - x_n| : k \geq 0\}\\ \leq \sup \{|x_{n+k} - x_{n+l}| : k,l \geq 0\} = \sup_{k,l\geq0}|x_{n+k}-x_{n+l}|$$
Further, for every $k,l \geq 0$ we have $|x_{n+k} - x_{n+l}|\leq |x_{n+k} - x_n| + |x_{n+l} - x_n|$, thus
$$\sup_{k,l\geq 0} |x_{n+k} - x_{n+l}| \leq \sup_{k,l\geq 0} |x_{n+k} - x_n| + |x_{n+l} - x_n| \leq \sup_{k,l\geq 0} |x_{n+k} - x_n| + \sup_{k,l\geq 0} |x_{n+l} - x_n|\\
= \sup_{k\geq 0} |x_{n+k} - x_n| + \sup_{l\geq 0} |x_{n+l} - x_n|= \sup_{k\geq 0} |x_{n+k} - x_n| + \sup_{k\geq 0} |x_{n+k} - x_n|\\
= 2 \sup_{k\geq 0} |x_{n+k} - x_n|$$

Comment: Why does the last inequality hold (replacing sup over l with sup over k)?

Comment: It is in fact an equality. Because it does not matter how you denote the indices. We are taking the supremum over the same values.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! Is the previous inequality also an equality? (replacing sup over k and l with supremum over k and supremum over l)

Comment: Yes good point. In fact it only became an inequality due copy and paste.